# How do I bind an IEnumerable to a Repeater in aspx markup?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, datasource, objectdatasource

I want to output all defined routes onto a page without any code behind, so I need to bind `RouteTable.Routes` to a Repeater in markup. How do I do that - `<asp:Repeater>` only has `DataSourceID` value available in markup, not DataSource. 
I assume I need to declare a DataSource for `RouteTable.Routes` and then provide its ID to the Repeater, but how do I do that?

Again, I need a solution without any code-behind, declarative only.

I'm using asp.net 4.0 (not MVC)

Comment: you have tagged objectdatasource...so i'm assuming you found the answer...lookup msdn for it. should give you some pointers

Comment: I haven't yet, I resorted to adding code behind for now.

Answer (score 5):

The asp.net Repeater control does have a DataSource property, and you can set it in the aspx markup (see screen shot below):

[image: Screen shot of Repeater markup intellisense]

Typically, what is done is to set the DataSource property to a databinding expression, which gets evaluates when the Page.DataBind() method is called.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="foo" DataSource = '<%# GetRoutes() %>' runat=server ></asp:Repeater>
```

I think you will still need some code on the page to call Page.DataBind() to initiate databinding on the aspx page.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.DataBind();
    }
```

This code could be put in the code-behind or, since you do not want to use code-behind, in a server code block in the aspx page.  But I believe it has to be called via C# code in a page event handler.  I do not believe this can be done in a purely declarative manner.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to do some minimal plumbing to make this work. Here is a sample for a gridview. You can adapt the technique for a repeater too.

DataSource Object Class:

```
public class MyObjectDataSourceEntity
{
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public DataTable GetSomeRecords()
    {
        DataTable names = new DataTable();
        DataColumn FirstName = names.Columns.Add();
        FirstName.DataType = typeof(string);
        FirstName.ColumnName = "FirstName";
        DataColumn LastName = names.Columns.Add();
        LastName.DataType = typeof(string);
        LastName.ColumnName = "LastName";

        DataRow row = names.NewRow();
        row[0] = "Arun";
        row[1] = "Jayapal";
        names.Rows.Add(row);
        row = names.NewRow();
        row[0] = "Namith";
        row[1] = "Chandran";
        names.Rows.Add(row);
        return names;
    }
```

You need to include the `System.ComponentModel` namespace.

Markup:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetSomeRecords" 
        TypeName="ObjectDataSourceDemo.MyObjectDataSourceEntity">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Note: I've added a datatable here because the gridview only understand that object when it comes to sorting right out-of-the-box. So you don't have to write extra code. Otherwise you use any `IEnumerable` object. But you'd have to write your own logic for sorting. Nothing to do with repeaters, but I thought I'd mention this.

Now you don't need to call `DataBind()` on anything!!!

PS: Once you've written code for your entity, build your project first. After this you can rely on your designer for adding the `ObjectDataSource` control onto the page. The wizard automatically detects supportable objects in the project, but you need to build solution first.